# Need to use add_index on migration for belongs_to/has_many relationship? (Rails 3.2, Active Record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My question is quite simple but I failed to find a clear answer.

I build a daily deals Rails app.

- Each deal has many products (has_many)
- Each product belongs to a deal

Folowing 2.3 from [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html),  I'll use this in my migration:

```
   class CreateDeal < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :deals do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.timestamps
      end

      create_table :products do |t|
        t.belongs_to :Deal
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
   end
```

Automatically, Rails/active records will add in the Product Table a column deals_id right?

Do I need to add an index on this deals_id column manually (like below) by adding to my migration `add_index` or is it done "automatically" because of the belongs_to/has_many relationship I have set?

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.belongs_to :Deal
  t.timestamps

  add_index :products, :deals_id 
end
```

Comment: shouldn't `t.belongs_to :Deal` be `t.belongs_to :deal`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do need to add the index yourself... However, if you use the command line generator for the model and use belongs_to, Rails will add in the index into the migration...

e.g.

```
rails g model product deal:belongs_to
```

would produce

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create table :products do |t|
      t.belongs_to :deal

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :products, :deal_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add the indexing yourself.

Also your migration isn't quite right, you need a 3rd table ie:

```
class CreateDeal < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :deals do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :deals_products do |t|
      t.belongs_to :deal
      t.belongs_to :product
    end
  end
end
```

As per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: This is the setup for a many-to-many relationship, not the simple has_many relationship Mathieu is talking about. I would personally avoid this setup unless you really need a many-to-many association because with this set up you have 3 tables requiring 2 indexes (which were left out of this migration) instead of 2 tables and one index.

As I understand it, while index speed up queries, they make save/update processes take longer so you're generally better off minimizing their use to only when you need them to reduce your overhead. In this case, it seems that one index should suffice.

Comment: Yeah my mistake - I don't know where I got that he was using many-to-many from.

Answer (score 1):

Mathieu, in situations of doubt like this, where you're not sure if something is being created or not created: it seems best to just explicitly create what you think is needed (in this case the index) and see what happens when you run the migration.

The logic behind this is that if your `:deal_id` column is already indexed and your migration tries to re-index it, it will get an error and the migration will rollback so you can fix it. However if you didn't add the index in your migration, you would obviously not get any errors but you'd have to take an extra step to check if the index exists.

```
class CreateDeal < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :deals do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :products do |t|
      t.belongs_to :Deal
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :products, :deal_id
  end
end
```

Note that you also want to add the index after the table creation process has complete. Using the add_index helper inside the create_table helper is probably going to cause an error.