# Does belongs_to creates an association in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following models:

```
class User
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Inside `create_table` for `items` I have:

```
t.belongs_to :person
```

I'm using Rails 5 and I saw this automatically creates an index for `person_id` inside the `items` table. However, according to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673193/need-to-use-add-index-on-migration-for-belongs-to-has-many-relationship-rails), this isn't supposed to happen.

Are the answers incorrect or was this added into Rails 5 (or some Rails 4.x version)?

Comment: `person_id`in the migration and the class is user. Is this right? Because if it is, this change things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does belongs_to creates an association in Rails 5?

Yes.

[`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-belongs_to) is an alias of [`references`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references) and it:

- creates `person_id` column in `items` table;
- adds index on `person_id` column.

Comment: @anemaria20 i don't remember and can't check as Im away from laptop. You can check in corresponding to rails 4 docs or test it, as i would do :)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't.

As @Andrey mentioned, `belongs_to` is an alias for `references`. If you follow the documentation, you'll see that `references` uses `connection.add_reference` internally. In `connection.add_reference` documentation you can see the [options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference), and mong them `index`:

```
:index

  Add an appropriate index. Defaults to false.

  See add_index for usage of this option.
```

So, by default, the `index` option which adds the index to the database is set to false. You should explicitly set it in the `references`.